# Scheme in Algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Sorry, this may not be a good question here. I am trying to read algebraic geometry by myself. I need some basic material related to scheme of commutative rings. could you please suggest me some text books or any lecture notes?
Thanks

Comment: Can't beat EGA for basic. :)

Comment: If you're looking for a conversation: Vakil. If you're looking for technical excellence: Liu. If you're looking for a middle ground: Gortz.

Comment: I recommend Geometry of Schemes by Eisenbud and Harris. The sources Alex mentioned are good texts that go further into the theory than E/H and in a style that you must get used to for further studies, but for first contact the first 150 pages of E/H gave me a feel for schemes that I struggled to get from the other standard sources. Also, note that EGA is generally used as a reference rather than a textbook (especially if learning on ones own) though certainly some people do use it as such.

Comment: @RagibZaman It depends what the OP's goal is. I think an absolutely fantastic combination is Vakil+Liu+E&H. Vakil will give you the general framework and direction in a digestible way. Liu will prove all of the things that the other two fumble with with excellent succinctness. E&H will give very soft, important intuition, as well as having a ton of amazing examples (OP should really read the whole of chapter 2 and 3 just for the examples).

Comment: @Alex. Your first comment is both witty and  accurate: +1

Comment: The same question has appeared a couple of times on math.SE and also mathoverflow. Use the search function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mumford's Red Book is a nice place to start.  Also Eisenbud and Harris.